# Getting inconsistent output when reading lines in Python?

Tags: python, file

Newbie programmer here. I just started learning Python and have come across my first real problem that's causing a bit of a headache.

Basically, I have created a program that reads a tab delimited text file and creates folders for the appropriate years and dates (as instructed by the text file). Within each month folder is a file called "archivedata.txt". This contains the row keys for the relevant entries in the text file. Everything is fine as far as this goes - the row keys are writing to each "archivedata.txt" file no problem.

My problem is that, when I try to count the lines in each text file, I'm getting the wrong output for just 1 text file . It has 1 row, but my program won't acknowledge this. When trying to read another .txt file which is the exact same, though (even down to the "\n" newline at the end of the file), it returns the correct answer.

I've tried putting both these files in the same directory and counting the lines, and they both return 1 in that case. So.. I'm stumped.

The file directory looks like this:

```
newprototype/
    archive/
        date/
            2012/
                12/
                    archivedata.txt # this is the file that won't read properly
            2014/
                06/
                    archivedata.txt # this file is nearly identical and reads no probs?
```

The code I'm using is called textfileparser_4.py and is stored in the 'newprototype' folder. Here is the code I'm using to read the files:

```
for files in os.walk(projectdir):
    if files[2] ==  ['archivedata.txt']: #if 'archivedata.txt' is found
        os.chdir(files[0])
        print os.getcwd()
        archivecount    =   0
        archivepoint    =   open("archivedata.txt")
        for line in archivepoint:
            archivecount    +=  1
        print archivecount
        print "-----"
```

Oh, and btw: the variable 'projectdir' points to the 'newprototype' directory :)

As requested, my output. This shows more directories than I gave in the example above. I only gave that example to show that '2014/06' also has a file with one row and that prints fine.

```
/dir/New Prototype/archive/date/2012/12
**There is nothing here** I expect '00004' to show up here.
-----
/dir/New Prototype/archive/date/2012/11
00003
00002
00001

-----
/dir/New Prototype/archive/date/2014/06
00010

-----
/dir/New Prototype/archive/date/2014/10
00007
00006
00005
```

**Update** I've managed to solve this by using another method that is more efficient and circumvents the need for me to do this. Still would be curious to know what could have caused this error, though. Thanks for the help!

**Grand update** Managed to fix this problem entirely by re-implementing the old code. I edited the part where the archivedata.txt files were being generated. Before closing them, I added *file.seek(0,0)* . This fixed everything. I'm not sure if this is something I should have known to do, but I learned the hard way. Hopefully this will be of use to someone out there!

Comment: "but my program won't acknowledge this" - what does it do instead? Try adding some extra print statements to your code to trace what is happening, e.g. `print files`. Also, your code will repeatedly open the same file because opening the file is not conditional upon having found it in the current directory.

Comment: Hi Stuart,

I didn't understand the second part of your post, and then realized I'd incorrectly indented the code in my original post (it always looked as above in the original program).

Instead of printing the current directory (2012/12/) and then "1", it prints "2012/12" and "0".

Comment: ok. Try replacing `for line in archivepoint: archivecount += 1` with `print archivepoint.read()` and see what files it's reading.

Comment: By the way, you should always close files that you open or use [with](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) -- `with open('archivedata.txt') as archivepoint:`. Although that doesn't seem to be what is causing the problem here.

Comment: When I try the archivepoint.read method, I get the following error:
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data.

Comment: Oops, didn't mean to send that just yet. Duly noted the second part of your response. Just for curiosity's sake, I moved the code to my linux box and tried to run it there, exact same issue so my code is definitely bunk.

Comment: That error happens if you include both `for line in archivepoint` (iteration) and `archivepoint.read` for the same file. Try removing the former to see what the latter does.

Comment: Sorry I just posted a bogus response there! So, it's basically recognizing all the files I'm looking for (and printing each row key), but not the one which is causing problems. In other words, the problem is still the same :( Not sure if I should just try rewriting the program from scratch at this point!

Comment: Maybe add expected and actual output to your post.

Comment: I don't think that output can possibly come from that section of code... it's showing several files in the 2012/11 and 2014/10 folders but your code only allows for one. It might help to show other parts of your code.

Comment: That's not separate files, they're separate rows within each 'archivedata.txt' file.

Comment: Then it's a mystery. Is it possible some other part of your programme is overwriting the file with a blank? Can you open it and read its contents from the python interactive shell?

Comment: Hi Stuart, I just posted an update. Got fed up with this so found a more efficient way to make my script and avoid this step. It will forever be a mystery to me. I'm not familiar with using the interactive shell to navigate directories, though I may try this tomorrow just to see what happens :)

Comment: Oh, and thanks very much for all your help tonight. You still managed to teach me a couple of tidbits, so cheers for that.

Answer (score 2):

Change this :

```
if files[2] ==  ['archivedata.txt']:
```

to:

```
if 'archivedata.txt' in files[2]:
     #do your stuff
     # insead of chdir, you can call function to with file and do your stuff
```

Better will be this:

```
for x,y,z in os.walk('your_path'):
    if 'your_file' in z:
        #Do your stuff
```

`os.walk` give three tuples i.e dir, subdirectory  and files in that directory

Here what you want:

```
def archive_count(myfile)
    archivecount = 0
    archivepoint = open(myfile)
    for line in archivepoint
        archivecount += 1
    print myfile + " : " + str(archivecount)  + " lines"
    print "-----"

 for x,y,z in os.walk('your_path'):
     if 'archivedata.txt' in z:
         archive_count(os.path.join(x,'archivedata.txt'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, mate. Tried both of those and still getting the same output.

Comment: @mailamarco check the last part i think this you want

Comment: I am getting the same numbers, unfortunately.

Comment: @mailamarco same numbers?? means same line in different files??

Comment: Sorry bud, I meant the same numbers as I was getting before. Still "1" for one file's linecount, "0" for the other.

Comment: @mailamarco you sure your `archivedata.txt` has some lines it it??

Comment: Positive! As I say, another one looks exactly the same (except the id is different - same length, etc.) and there's no issue at all with it.